# angularjs: ng-click on <a> not working, works on <button>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is the Javascript

```
    function gotoUrl($scope, $location, $http, $window) {
      $scope.setRoute = function (route) {
        $location.path(route);
    };
```

My code is

```
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar">
            <li><a href="#" data-ng-click="setRoute('summary')"><span
                    class="icon-bar-chart"></span> Summary</a></li>
            <li><a href="#
            " data-ng-click="setRoute('transactions')"><span
                    class="icon-reorder"></span>
                Transactions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-ng-click="setRoute('budgets')"><span
                    class="icon-calendar"></span>
                Budgets</a></li>
        </ul>
```

The routes are configured as

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/summary', {templateUrl: '../static/partials/summary.html', controller: 'SummaryController'})
        .when('/transactions', { templateUrl: '../static/partials/listTransaction.html', controller: 'TransactionsManagerController'})
        .when('/profile', {templateUrl: '../static/partials/profile.html', controller: 'ProfileController'})
        .when('/new', {templateUrl: '../static/partials/addTransaction.html', controller: 'TransactionAddController'})
        .when('/budgets', {templateUrl: '../static/partials/budgets.html'})
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/summary'});
});
```

When I click on `Transactions`, it takes me to `Summary`

When I change the code from `<a>` to `<button>`, it works, what is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:a

> Modifies the default behavior of the html A tag so that the default
>   action is prevented **when the href attribute is empty**.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `href=""` instead of `href="#"`. If you are using hashbang mode routing, the latter results in a full-page reload, which is what seems to be happening in your case as well. Any link with `href="#"` that you click will cause your app to fully reload the page and load the default route -- in your case `Summary`.

Comment: Or set the href like this: <a href data-ng-click="setRoute('summary')">Click</a>

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of gotoUrl function and modify DOM to

```
<a href="#/transactions"><span></span>Transactions</a>
```

AngularJS will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

change this code segment

```
<li><a href="#
        " data-ng-click="setRoute('transactions')"><span
                class="icon-reorder"></span>
            Transactions</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a href="/transactions"><span
                class="icon-reorder"></span>
            Transactions</a></li>
```